# timer with delay, reset and restart? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

So I basically have a timer which counts 1 number every 4 seconds.
It stops when it hits 10.

Q: How do i make it so that the timer stops at 10 for a couple of seconds, then starts counting again at 1?

```
    var i = 8;
setInterval( increment, 4000);
function increment(){
if(i<=10)
{
console.log(i);
 $('.increase').html('').append(i);
i++;
}

}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0t3s8erj/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `else`!

```
var counter = 0

function increment () {
  counter++

  if (counter <= 10) {
    console.log(counter)
  } else {
    clearInterval(incrementInterval)

    setTimeout(function () {
      incrementInterval = setInterval(increment, 4000)
    }, 10000)
  }
}

incrementInterval = setInterval(increment, 4000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! didn't really think of that. However, the code isn't working.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I have :) anyhow, another guy have solved it already. + helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this where you run an interval timer until you get to the max count, then you clear that timer and start a new timer for the amount of time you want to pause and then when that delay timer fires, you call your function again to start it all over.

Here's a working code snippet (I set the times short here for demo purposes, but you can set them to whatever you want):

```js
function runTimer(selector, start, end, interval, delay) {
    var cntr = start;
    $(selector).html(cntr);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        ++cntr;
        $(selector).html(cntr);
        if (cntr >= end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            setTimeout(function() {
                runTimer(selector, 1, end, interval, delay);
            }, delay);
        }
    }, interval);
}

runTimer('.increase', 8, 10, 300, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="increase">8</span>/10
```

Comment: Great! However, if i set the "start" value to 8. it will jump down to 2 after the  first count. how can i fix this?
eg. startvalue: 8->10. reset. 1-10.

Comment: @Joel - See the change to my answer.  This will go 8-->10, then after that first count, it will go 1-->10 from then on.

Comment: Bonus: would it be possible to stop the code the 2nd time at the value 6?
so. 8-10-> reset. 1->6.

i tried:

 `setTimeout(function() {
                runTimer(selector, 1, 10, interval, delay);
            }, delay);
        }
    }, interval);
}

runTimer('.increase', 8, 6, 7500, 10000);`

Comment: @Joel - you should be able to modify the code as desired on your own - you can add more arguments to `runtimer()` if you want.  I don't know if I understood exactly what you were asking for, but here's one idea: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mk3nL97q/6/

Comment: Hi, thanks again. I really appreciate that you're taking your time in helping me with this. What i meant was that I only want the timer to reset once. then stop at 6 for example. So. 8->10. reset. 1->6 (STOP).